# Declaring an excel formula as a constant in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I received some help on here to declare a formula as a constant in vba. I have approximately ten formulas that are all similar variations on a theme. I've set 9 of them and they work fine the below one throws up a Run-time error (Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Option Explicit
Public Const csFORMULA = "=CONCATENATE(""AVABIS"",IF(I2=0,"""",CONCATENATE(UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(LEFT(I2,3))),UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(RIGHT(I2,3))))),IF(O2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(O2,""0"","""")))),IF(R2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(R2,""0"","""")))),IF(W2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(W2,""0"","")))),IF(AB2=0,"""",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(AB2,""0"",""""))),IF(AC2=0,"""",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(AC2,""0"",""""))),IF(AD2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AD2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z"")),IF(AF2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AF2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z"")),IF(AH2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AH2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z""))))"


Sub AvivaBIS()


    Dim lr         As Long
    Dim cl         As Range
    Dim rng        As Range
    Dim mssg       As String
    Dim ws         As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

        lr = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'add the formula to generate the unique key
        Range("B2:B" & lr).Formula = csFORMULA
        Range("B2:B" & lr) = Range("B2:B" & lr).Value


    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've deleted the other non-essential code from the above to simplify my question.

Steps I've taken so far:

Tried pasting the original formula straight in the sheet - this works.

Tried replacing the declared formula as something simple (e.g. A1+A2) - this works.

Double checked the quotation marks to see I have the right number - these seem fine.

Copied another very similar formula from the others I've created - this works also.

Any suggestions on what else I could look at to fix this would be gratefully received. Is there a way to get more information when it throws up a run-time error?

Thanks as always for taking the time to look.

Comment: Can't you just input the formula to some hidden cell and copy paste it to the required Range? This is safer than inputing a string as locale can change (list separators)

Comment: Debug.print the constant, then try copy/pasting it to B2.  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed doubling up on one set of empty string double quotes (just after W2 about midway through the formula) and had an extra closing bracket at the end.

```
Public Const csFORMULA = "=CONCATENATE(""AVABIS"",IF(I2=0,"""",CONCATENATE(UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(LEFT(I2,3))),UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(RIGHT(I2,3))))),IF(O2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(O2,""0"","""")))),IF(R2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(R2,""0"","""")))),IF(W2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(W2,""0"","""")))),IF(AB2=0,"""",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(AB2,""0"",""""))),IF(AC2=0,"""",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(AC2,""0"",""""))),IF(AD2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AD2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z"")),IF(AF2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AF2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z"")),IF(AH2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AH2,""-"",""X""),""."",""Y""),""0"",""Z"")))"
```

Comment: The method I use is to first get the formula working correctly as a formula in a worksheet cell. I then copy this to the VBE on a line all by itself and (while ignoring any error messages) use Ctrl+H to replace all " with "". I take the modified string and cut and paste it where I want it inside yet another set of double quotes. HTH.

Comment: thanks, I've been trying to figure out a way to convert the formula from one that worked in the function to one that was declared.